# vs.net2008 (sp1) + TFS: Data Source connection info overwritten when project opened

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, connection

I've changed the connection string info in the datasource and saved it.

I haven't sync'd or downloaded any changes from TFS

Yet each time I open the solution, it has the connstr info as though I'd just 'got latest' from TFS

Is this a bug and is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Visual Studio options. Go to Tools-->Options-->Visual Studio Team Foundation

See if you have Get latest version of item on check out selected.

Also check Tools-->Options-->Source Control-->Environment

and under Source Control Environment Settings see if you have "Get everything when a solution or project is opened" selected.

Those two options combined would probably produce the behavior you're describing.

Comment: I don't want the latest version. I don't care what the source controlled settings are, I want to set it to point somewhere else. I am not updating (from TFS) this file at all after the very first ever get, but it is not persisting the values I'm saving locally.

Comment: I know that's not what you want, but if your settings are set that way, then it could be causing the undesirable behavior.

If you don't ever plan on connecting to TFS again after pulling the solution down the first time, then make a backup copy of the directory and remove the Workspace Mapping altogether.  Make sure you have a backup though because changing your workspace can delete the files if you've eliminated that directory from your workspace.

Also make sure that you don't have a ReadOnly flag set on the solution directory or child items.

Comment: Sorry I can't think of any other ordinary reason why you'd experience that.